# Enum localization using Binding and different languages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, enums

I try to find solution to output localized enums from resources using Binding.

Now I bind enums by common way like that:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="RootConverterType" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" >
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="settingsManager:RootConverterType"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

`<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RootConverterType}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CameraPosition.Config.UI.ValueConverterType.W, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"`

This is not localized enums, but I wish to use localization for them (using different languages from resources) and with conversion from localized string to enum in background without `ComboBox` events and explicit conversion. Is this possible? If yes, could someone provide simple code example please?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible if you import multi xaml files to implement localization.

Because if you import languages to xaml , they are static resources. I suggested you use Binding dynamic resource, and import resources in cs files to initialize resource key.

Xaml Like this:

```
 Content="{DynamicResource UID_AppCommon_MiniPA_Close}"
```

CS Like this:

```
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(your resource file);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a wrapper struct to solve this problem:

```
public enum AttributeType {
  Bool, 
  Number,
  String 
}//AttributeType


public struct AttributeTypeWrapper {

    public AttributeTypeWrapper(AttributeType type) {
      this.type = type;
    }

    private AttributeType type;

    public AttributeType Type {
      get {
        return type;
      }
      set {
        type = value;
      }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
      switch(type) {
        case AttributeType.Bool:
          return Properties.Resources.txtBool;
        case AttributeType.Number:
          return Properties.Resources.txtNumber;
        case AttributeType.String:
          return Properties.Resources.txtString;
        default:
          return "Invalid AttributeType";
      }
    }
  }// AttributeTypeWrapper
```

Note that it is a **struct** not a **class**. So it is a value type and can easyly set as `SelectedItem` of a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` for example.

To go a step further, you can implement an IValueConverte for simple Binding:

```
/// <summary>


/// Convert a AttributeType into its wrapper class to display strings from resources
  /// in the selected language
  /// </summary>
  [ValueConversion(typeof(AttributeType), typeof(AttributeTypeWrapper))]
  public class AttributeTypeToWrapperConverter : IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      return new AttributeTypeWrapper((AttributeType)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      return ((AttributeTypeWrapper)value).Type;
    }
  }
```

Then you can bind `SelectedItem` directly to the `enum` type:

```
<AttributeTypeToWrapperConverter x:Key="convertAttrTypeToWrapper"/>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataTypes}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDataType, Converter={StaticResource convertAttrTypeToWrapper}}"/>
```

`DataTypes` is an Array of `AttributeTypeWrapper` structs. `SelectedDataType` is of type 
`AttributeType`. (You can convert the ItemsSource as well).

This works pretty fine for me.

Comment: Something wrong here. I made exactly the same and got just empty combobox. Are you sure this is enough?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to localize enums:

Here is my class which you can use ase an example:
ru_RU and en_US - resources file names.

public class EnumLocalizationManager : BindableObject
    {
        public Language language;
        private CommonLocalization commonLang;
        private ObservableCollection rootCoverterTypes;

```
    public EnumLocalizationManager()
    {
        commonLang = CommonLocalization.GetInstance;
        EnumLanguage = commonLang.Lang;
    }

    //Коллекция для локализации enum RootConverterType
    public static Dictionary<Language, ObservableCollection<string>> RootConverterLocalization = new Dictionary<Language, ObservableCollection<string>>()
    {
        {
            Language.ru_RU, new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeUndefined, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeAuto, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeNumber, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeExponent, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeDecimal, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeInteger
            }
        },
        {
            Language.en_US, new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeUndefined, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeAuto, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeNumber, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeExponent, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeDecimal, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeInteger
            }
        }
    };

    //Коллекция для локализации enum ConverterType
    public static Dictionary<Language, ObservableCollection<string>> ConverterLocalization = new Dictionary<Language, ObservableCollection<string>>()
    {
        {
            Language.ru_RU, new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeAuto, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeNumber, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeExponent, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeDecimal, ru_RU.CameraEnumConverterTypeInteger
            }
        },
        {
            Language.en_US, new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeAuto, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeNumber, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeExponent, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeDecimal, en_US.CameraEnumConverterTypeInteger
            }
        }
    };




    public ObservableCollection<string> RootConverterTypes
    {
        get { return rootCoverterTypes; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ConverterTypes
    {
        get { return coverterTypes; }
    }



    public Language EnumLanguage
    {
        get { return language; }
        set
        {
            language = value;
            ChangeEnumLanguage();

        }
    }

    private void ChangeEnumLanguage()
    {
        if (RootConverterLocalization.ContainsKey(language))
        {
            rootCoverterTypes = RootConverterLocalization[language];
        }

        if (ConverterLocalization.ContainsKey(language))
        {
            coverterTypes = ConverterLocalization[language];
        }


        RaisePropertyChanged();
        RaisePropertyChangedByName("RootConverterTypes");
        RaisePropertyChangedByName("ConverterTypes");
   }
}
```

}

BindableObject class is class which incapsulates INotifyPropertyChanged.
First of all - your enums must be numbered (it is needed for ValueConverter)
for ex:
public enum ConverterType
    {
        Auto = 0,
        Number = 1,
        Exponential = 2,
        Decimal = 3,
        Integer = 4
    }

```
public enum RootConverterType
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Auto = 1,
    Number = 2,
    Exponential = 3,
    Decimal = 4,
    Integer = 5
}
```

and the last part - ValueConvert by itself:

class EnumCameraVariantToLocalizedStringConverter:ConverterBase
    {
        public EnumCameraVariantToLocalizedStringConverter()
        {

```
    }

    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)(CameraVariant)value;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int index = (int)value;
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                return CameraVariant.Undefined;
            case 1:
                return CameraVariant.FirstPerson;
            case 2:
                return CameraVariant.ThirdPerson;
            case 3:
                return CameraVariant.Flight;
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

I use inheritance from base class just to use makrup extenstions without adding resources for each converter.

And the Binding itself:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource CameraMainSelectorStyle}"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumLocalizationManager}, Path=CameraVariant}"  
                                            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CameraSettingsManager.StartUpCameraModeFilter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={valueConverters:EnumCameraVariantToLocalizedStringConverter}}"
                                            Tag="{Binding Path=CameraSettingsManager.StartUpCameraModeFilter, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            SelectionChanged="StartUpCameraTypeFilter_OnSelectionChanged"/>
```

Here is binding enum to Combobox. I hope evething is clear. One thing here. If you want to change language on fly, you must add some code for not loosing selected item after language changing:

```
if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                if (((ComboBox) sender).Tag != null)
                {
                    CameraVariant behavior = (CameraVariant) ((ComboBox) sender).Tag;
                    ((ComboBox) sender).SelectedIndex = (int) behavior;
                }
            }
```

That all. Looks a little bit scary, but there is nothing hard.